# Subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an element of finite order in its fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Is there a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an element of finite order (not the identity!) in its fundamental group?

I think the real projective plane is such a subset as its fundamental group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2$. If $f:\pi_1(\Bbb{R}P^2)\to\Bbb{Z}_2$ is an isomorphism and $[a]\in\pi_1(\Bbb{R}P^2)$ ($[a]$ is not the identity), then $f([a]\cdot[a])=f([a])\cdot f([a])=0$, which means that $[a]\cdot[a]$ is the identity.

The only problem might be the assumption $\Bbb{R}P^2\subset\Bbb{R}^3$. But as we can think of $\Bbb{R}P^2$ as the unit sphere with its antipodal points identified, this seems plausible (visually).

Is my visual intuition wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes - $\mathbb{R}P^2$ does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but it does embed into $\mathbb{R}^4$).

Comment: A related topic: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36279/the-fundamental-group-of-every-subset-of-mathbbr2-is-torsion-free

Comment: What kind of subsets are you interested in? Arbitrary? Open?  Simplicial subcomplexes? For arbitrary subsets (even compact ones) this appears to be an open problem.

Comment: I was interested in arbitrary sets.
@Matt I googled it and it seems to have a very sophisticated (for me) proof

Comment: @Seirios Thanks for the reference, I will read it carefully soon.