# For what types of manifolds are all closed 2-forms exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

According to the Maxwell equations the electromagentic tensor $F$ is a closed $2$-form, i.e. $\mathrm dF=0$. Why can we deduce that $F$ is exact, i.e. that there exists a $1$-form $A$ such that $\mathrm dA=F$? For what class of manifolds does this hold?

Comment: I think this is exactly saying that the second de Rham cohomology of the manifold is zero. In particular, this holds for Euclidean spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "every closed form is exact" imply simply connected for a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689092/does-every-closed-form-is-exact-imply-simply-connected-for-a-connected-open-se)

Comment: It always holds locally. It holds globally on contractible spaces by the Poincaré lemma (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+lemma)

Comment: @GiulioR Thank you for the reference!

Comment: @GiulioR TBH I don't understand why this follows from the Poincaré lemma (corollary 2.2). If you could elaborate a bit, that would make a perfect answer!

Comment: that's exact one should look at corollary 2.2 there. It says that if a manifold is contractible then all closed $n$-forms are exact for $n\geq 1$. That is what is meant by " the de Rham cohomology is concentrated on the ground field in degree 0" (because the de Rham cohomology is a graded vector space whose part of degree $n$ is the quotient of the space of closed $n$forms over the space of exact $n$forms). See also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma

Comment: @GiulioR "in degree 0" means "in $H_{\mathrm{dR}}^0(M)$"? In particular "the ground field in degree 0" is a subset of $H_{\mathrm{dR}}^0(M)$"?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the comment, I have edited the title.

Comment: There also happen to be non-contractible manifolds for which $H^2_{dR} = 0$, for example $S^n$ for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you for the comment. I didn't know about the de Rham cohomology and I think that this perfectly answers my question.

Comment: Also I have checked it and I can confirm that you are right. This is also stated explicitly in Lee's book from 2012:  "For $0 \leq p \leq \dim M$, the definition implies that $H_{\mathrm{dR}}^p (M)=0$ if and only if every closed $p$-form on $M$ is exact."

Comment: @KurtG. To answer your question: I would rather say that the first comment answers my question. I thought that I was considering an issue that got little attention, but now I see that this is a question about de Rham cohomologies, a very well understood topic as the comments above show.