# Fundamental groups of path connected subspaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Does every path connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ have a fundamental group the trivial or an infinity group?

For example, for convex subspaces we know that, but if we take only path connected subespaces what happen?

Answer (score 2):

Every reasonable path connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has fundamental group a free group, which is either trivial or infinite. "Reasonable" means homotopy equivalent to a tubular neighborhood of it in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and in particular means homotopy equivalent to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a noncompact surface, and every connected noncompact surface has fundamental group a free group; see, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces).

An example of an unreasonable path connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring), whose fundamental group is not free.

Comment: However, Hawaiian earring has an infinite fundamental group

Comment: Do you know any easy argument to prove that fundamental group of hawiian earring is not free?? I know that it is uncountable, but proving it is not free seems difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was answered in affirmative by George Lowther here:

[Is the fundamental group of every subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ torsion free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36279/the-fundamental-group-of-every-subset-of-mathbbr2-is-torsion-free)

More precisely, he proves that if $X$ is a subset of any closed surface $S$, for instance, $S=S^2$, and $x\in X$, then $\pi_1(X,x)$ is torsion free.

Note that no assumption is made about the nature of the subset $X$, it is not assumed to be "reasonable".

From this, it follows that if $\pi_1(X,x)$ is nontrivial, it contains a nontrivial element $\gamma$, which, then, necessarily has infinite order. Therefore, $\pi_1(X,x)$ is either trivial or infinite.