# Fundamental group of a planar set: torsion free and no $\mathbb Z^2$ subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, plane-geometry

A quick topology question.

If $X$ is some subset of the plane $\mathbb R^2$ (equipped with the subspace topology) and we consider the fundamental group $G = \pi_1(X,x)$ for some $x \in X$, is the following reasonable to say?

- All non-trivial elements of $G$ have infinite order.
- There is no subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$.

If not, what else does one need to assume?

Take care, and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question has been answered in the affirmative in [Is the fundamental group of every subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ torsion-free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36279). However, this is a highly non-trival result.

The second assertion is true for compact $X$. See

Fischer, Hanspeter, and Andreas Zastrow. "The fundamental groups of subsets of closed surfaces inject into their first shape groups." Algebraic & Geometric Topology 5.4 (2005): 1655-1676

https://www.emis.de/journals/UW/agt/ftp/main/2005/agt-5l67.pdf

See Corollary 7 in this paper. I guess it is true also for non-compact $X$, but I do not know a proof.

Comment: Yeah that seems the ticket. Thanks!